# Copy a range of text from csv column in pandas and python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a csv file that I have imported into Pandas. Now it has almost 45 columns of data and each column has more than 100 lines of information. Now I need to select only the range of text that starts with a Date Stamp at the start and ends with a Date Stamp.

Ex :

```
<GMT2015-09-01 00:03:29GMT> Hi Rajiv<GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT> Hi Ram <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT>
```

So, in such structure I need to select only the first paragraph of datestamp to datestamp into a new data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) data in column `Ticket Description` by `<>` and then  select output `DataFrame` by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). Last you can [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) starts and ends whitespaces.

Notice: It works nice if `<>` are only in start and end od each datetime.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticket Description':['<GMT2015-09-01 00:03:29GMT> Hi Rajiv<GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT> Hi Ram <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT> ']})
print (df)
                                  Ticket Description
0  <GMT2015-09-01 00:03:29GMT> Hi Rajiv<GMT2015-0...

print (df['Ticket Description'].str.split(r'[<>]', expand=True).iloc[:, 2].str.strip())
0    Hi Rajiv
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Comment: These are not separate columns, let me paste a copy of it below :

Comment: <GMT2015-09-01 00:03:29GMT> 
Hi Rajiv, 
 
As part of our job
 
Request for your approval. 
 
Thanks 
<GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT>                                                                Hi Ram, 
 
Request Approved
 
Thanks                                                                                           <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT>                                                               This is the kind of information present in the column of the dataframe. From a individual column I need to extract the txt present in between the first timestamp to 2nd timestamp.

Comment: Ok, is possible add sample of your csv if not data confidental? Because if I understand well, `datestamp Hi,
      --------------
      --------------
      datestamp Hi,
      --------------
      --------------
      datestamp Hi,
      --------------
      --------------
      datestamp Hi,
      --------------
      --------------
      datestamp` is in one line of `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Ok, can you add this information to question? Because in comment is not clear if this is 2 rows of dataframe or only one. Thanks.

Comment: These are in a single row called Ticket Description which has multiple columns and each column has multiple lines of text. I need to extract the text present in the columns. As you see in the example : <GMT2015-09-01 00:03:29GMT> Hi Rajiv, As part of our job Request for your approval. Thanks <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT> Hi Ram, Request Approved Thanks <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT>. I need to extract the text in between 1st timestamp and 2nd timestamp.

Comment: I think I understand, is it `df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticket Description':['<GMT2015-09-01 00:03:29GMT> Hi Rajiv, As part of our job Request for your approval. Thanks <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT> Hi Ram, Request Approved Thanks <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT> ']})

print (df)` ?

Comment: Super, please check solution.

Answer (score 0):

Regex and pandas apply should achieve what you want. I'm assuming u want only the text between the very first and second timestamp. I have created a dataframe with your message, except the second one starts with 2. `>(.+?)<` in the regex searches for the any number of characters surrounded by a `>` and `<`. The `?` makes it non greedy so it doesnt go from the first timestamp all the way to the last and stops at the first match.

Sample code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2],"ticket_desc":[r"<GMT2015-09-01 00:03:29GMT> Hi Rajiv, As part of our job Request for your approval. Thanks <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT> Hi Ram, Request Approved Thanks <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT>.",r"<GMT2015-09-01 00:03:29GMT> 2Hi Rajiv, As part of our job Request for your approval. Thanks <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT> Hi Ram, Request Approved Thanks <GMT2015-09-01 19:08:15GMT>."]})
def finder(x):
    return re.findall(">(.+?)<",x)[0]
data["ticket_desc"] = data["ticket_desc"].apply(finder)
print data["ticket_desc"][0]
print data["ticket_desc"][1]
```

Output:

```
Hi Rajiv, As part of our job Request for your approval. Thanks 


 2Hi Rajiv, As part of our job Request for your approval. Thanks
```